# Effective use of enterprise keywords

Tags: 2010, enterprise-keywords, tags

I am site collection (not sharepoint) administrator. Our product owner would like us to move away from a strict document library and folder structure to a cloud-like approach, where all public documents are stored in one document library with metadata and use that instead of the folders. 
What I have in mind is a webpart on the page with all the tags, that the user could click an narrow the search, allowing multiple selections. Like filter for reports, then refine to finance.
 Tags didn't really work as expected: I tagged a document, added a tag cloud webpart to the page, but clicking on a tag navigated away to "mysite" (why?) and didn't bring up any result. 
 I am now experimenting with the Enterprise keywords, that also do not seem to work as I expected. First I couldn't find any out-of-the-box webpart that lists all the keywords for filtering. So I went further with text filter, to see that at least that works. Well, search works, but only with complete match. So "fin" or "fin*" doesn't find any "finance" tagged documents.
Can someone give me a hint how to achieve the required result with site collection administrator rights only?